# Not scaling in landscape mode?

Tags: android, orientation, scaling

When i set to some view weight or height in dpi on others screen resolutions and densityes in portraint mode scaling work fine. But it don't work whet turn to lanscape!

I can make resources files for all densityes and resolution, but it not good solution for me beacause i have a lot of layouts.

I try to set anyDensity to false, use px or sp, turn off and on screen resolution. And nothing hapens.

There is an another solution to anything?

Thanks for replyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you experiencing bad landscape layout when creating fixed dpi widths and heights?
Create **layout-land** folder in the res folder. Create xml layout files for all the screens you would like to have in dpi dimensions for landscape.

Comment: Yes, i have that problem in landscape, but in portraint all ok.  May be your solution is the one. I have many layouts and i don't want to create all of then for all resolution and dencityes. But apparently no other solutions!